# Java Swing Dialog Window focus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dialog

In my application I have a main window and a utility popup dialog that is shown when the user clicks on a menu item. My issue is that if another program (say firefox) is opened over the java application, this obviously hides the java application. This is OK - but when the user then clicks on my java application again, only the main window is shown - the utility popup dialog is still hidden under firefox. I would like to design it such that when the user interacts with the main window in any way the utility popup dialog is also brought to the front.

I've tried adding a MouseInputListener to the main frame to bring the utility dialog to the front but this also transfers focus to it, which I don't want.

```
private MouseInputAdapter onWindowClick = new MouseInputAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (scheduleDialog != null)
            scheduleDialog.toFront(); // the utility dialog
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the utility popup dialog is still hidden

When the dialog is created you need to specify the main window as the owner of the dialog.

Then when you click on the icon for the window, the dialog will display as well.

Read the JDialog API for the proper constructor to use.